# Efficiently write JSON to sqlite database

Tags: python, json, sqlite, pandas, bigdata

I'm trying to write big JSON (minimum 500MB) files to a database. I wrote a script which works and is kind of memory friendly, but it is very slow. Any suggestion on how to make it more efficient?

My JSON files (remote sensing measurements extracted from google earth engine) are formatted like that:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-55.347046,-12.179673],"geodesic":true,"type":"Point"},"id":"LT52240692005129COA00_2","properties":{"B1":null,"B2":null,"B3":null,"B4":null,"B5":null,"B7":null,"description":"","id":0.0,"name":""},"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-52.726481,-13.374343],"geodesic":true,"type":"Point"},"id":"LT52250692005184COA00_10","properties":{"B1":217,"B2":497,"B3":424,"B4":2633,"B5":1722,"B7":747,"description":"","id":8.0,"name":""},"type":"Feature"}]}
```

Here is the script that reads the JSON, parses it and write to the database.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import sqlite3

# Variables
JSON_file = '../data/LT5oregon.geojson'
db_src = '../data/SR_ee_samples.sqlite'
table_name = 'oregon'
chunk_size = 5000

# Read JSON file
with open(JSON_file) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

# Create database connection
con = sqlite3.connect(db_src)

# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
# Initialize count for row index
count = 0

# Main loop
for feature in data['features']:
    json_feature = feature['properties']
    if json_feature['B1'] is not None:
        # Build metadata
        meta = feature['id'].split('_')
        meta_dict = {'scene_id': meta[0], 'feature_id': int(meta[1])}
        # Append meta data to feature data
        json_feature.update(meta_dict)
        # Append row to df
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(json_feature, index=[count]))
        count += 1
        if len(df) >= chunk_size: # When df reaches a certain number of rows, empty it to db
            df.to_sql(name = table_name, con = con, if_exists='append')
            df = pd.DataFrame()

# write remaining rows to db
df.to_sql(name = table_name, con = con, if_exists='append')
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit from a profiler (like `line_profiler` or [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html)) to evaluate which part of your code is taking time.

My bet would be on the append call on the dataframe, I'm suspecting it has to copy the whole dataframe every time to keep a contiguous array (just like numpy). Maybe make a list of elements and then create the dataframe out of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to export in json lines format then data chunking is supported by pandas when reading in and you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.read_json(json_file, orient="records",
                  chunksize=chunksize, lines=True) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        chunk.to_sql('table_name', 
                     con=con, 
                     if_exists='append', 
                     index=False)
```